# How can I implement a close tab button in Kendo Tabstrip with Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have a `kendo-tabstrip` and I need add the ability to close tabs. I created a directive `myCloseTab` and applied it to a `button` element inside the `kendoTabTitle` directive, and I am able to successfully listen for click events on that element. So far so good.

However, I do not see how to access the `kendoTabStrip` element so I can invoke `kendoTabStrip.remove(i)`, where `i` is the index of the tab. I can reference `this.elementRef` from the click listener, but I don't think walking up the DOM tree is the ideal Angular approach.

Kendo TabStrip:

```
<kendo-tabstrip>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab
        *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
        [selected]="tab.selected"
        [disabled]="tab.disabled">

        <ng-template kendoTabTitle >
            <span>{{ tab.title }}</span>
            <button myCloseTab></button>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template kendoTabContent>
            <div>{{ tab.data }</div>
        </ng-template>

    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

myCloseTab directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCloseTab]'
})
export class CloseTabDirective {

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick() {
        console.log(this.elementRef);
    }

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'closeIcon');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a reference in the element you want to access like this:

```
<kendo-tabstrip #reference>
<kendo-tabstrip-tab
    *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
    [selected]="tab.selected"
    [disabled]="tab.disabled">

    <ng-template kendoTabTitle >
        <span>{{ tab.title }}</span>
        <button myCloseTab></button>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <div>{{ tab.data }</div>
    </ng-template>

</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

and the you can access this in .ts file by doing this :

```
@ViewChild('reference') tabStrip : KendoTabStripConstructor;
```

then you'll be able to access the methods of the tabStrip Object including that remove method. Personally I never used Kendo but I already used this approach with one of the primeng components and it's working just fine. I just looked kendo up and I think it's the same principle as primeng so this should work for you.